# Prometheus - combining average used cpu query with nodes which have specific label

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to write query in Prometheus which gets the average used cpu of nodes with specific node label.

The used cpu query for a single host is:

```
(1-avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",node=~host1"}[5m]))) * 100
```

The query which returns list of nodes with specific value is:

```
kube_node_labels{label_department="prod"}
```

How do I combine both queries?

Thanks in advance.

The output of both querires:

- **node_cpu_seconds_total**

```
{cpu="0",endpoint="metrics",host_ip="150.130.1.2",instance="150.130.1.2:2323",job="expose-node-metrics",mode="idle",namespace="prometheus",node="host001",pod="export-monitor",service="expose-node-metrics"}
```

- **kube_node_labels**

```
{endpoint="http",host_ip="150.130.1.2",instance="150.130.1.2:2323",job="expose-node-metrics",label_department="prod",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",label_kubernetes_io_hostname="host001",label_kubernetes_io_os="linux",label_node_role_kubernetes_io_worker="true",namespace="prometheus",node="host001",pod="export-monitor",service="expose-node-metrics"}
```

Comment: It i possible but you need a common label between `node_cpu_seconds_total` and `node_cpu_seconds_total`. Can you please add to your question a sample of node metrics related to a sample of labels metric ?

Comment: Please see updated output

Answer (score 0):

When you want to filter a metric from another metric, you can use [binary set operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) to select what you want. In this case, using `AND`:

> vector1 and vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of vector1 for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets.

You will notice that the `node` label is present in both metrics and that what you can use it to filter node metrics:

```
irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m]) AND ON(node) kube_node_labels{label_department="prod"}
```

Then, if you want to have the average by node:

```
avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m]) AND ON(node) kube_node_labels{label_department="prod"}) BY(node)
```